# Calculating column value based on previous row and column using lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have this pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
index up_walk    down_walk   up_avg  down_avg
  0   0.000000   17.827148  0.36642   9.06815
  1   1.550781    0.000000      NaN       NaN
  2   0.957031    0.000000      NaN       NaN
  3   0.000000    2.878906      NaN       NaN
```

I wanted to calculate the missing values that currently are NAN by this formula:

```
df['up_avg'][i] = df['up_avg'][i-1] * 12 + df['up_walk'][i]
```

explanation: I want to calculate for every row the value based on the previous row in the same column, plus the value in the current row from a different column. And that for every row with missing values. and Continue this calculation to the end of the dataframe. In this case, I have a dependency in every new row calculation that is based on the previous up_avg value calculation.

The problem is that using a loop is very slow because of the large dataframe(10K)

Can anyone please help implement a lambda function for this?

if this is not possible, can anyone share a script for an efficient loop?

I tried a lot of things with no success like this:

```
df['up_avg'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.where((x.up_avg != None), x.up_avg.shift() * 12 + x.up_walk, x.up_avg)))

got an error -  "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'up_avg'"
```

and also using shift to create new columns and then using a lambda function with no success

I expect that my dataframe will look like this at the end:

```
index up_walk    down_walk   up_avg  down_avg
  0   0.000000   17.827148  0.36642   9.06815
  1   1.550781    0.000000  5.947821  108.8178
  2   0.957031    0.000000  72.330883 1305.8136
  3   0.000000    2.878906  867.970596  15672.642106
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **np.roll** instead of **shift**. Also, if you are using apply, you must specify an **axis**:

````
#keep going until there is no nan value left
status=True
while status:
    df['up_avg'] = np.where((np.isnan(df.up_avg)==True), np.roll(df.up_avg,1) * 12 +df.up_walk ,df.up_avg)
    if df['up_avg'].isnull().sum() == 0:
        status=False
        
status=True
while status:
    df['down_avg'] = np.where((np.isnan(df.down_avg)==True), np.roll(df.down_avg,1) * 12 +df.down_walk ,df.down_avg)
    if df['down_avg'].isnull().sum() == 0:
        status=False

print(df)
    up_walk   down_walk     up_avg      down_avg
0   0.0       17.827148     0.36642     9.06815
1   1.550781  0.0           5.947821    108.81779999999999
2   0.957031  0.0           72.330883   1305.8136
3   0.0       2.878906      867.970596  15672.642106

```
````

Answer (score 0):

Based on the math you're trying to implement here, each missing `nan` value is given by:

```
up_avg1 = 12*up_avg0 + up_walk1
up_avg2 = 12*up_avg1 + up_walk2
up_avg3 = 12*up_avg2 + up_walk3
```

...and so on. Expressed in this way, each new value of `up_avg` depends on the previous value of `up_avg`, which forces you to loop.

Unpacking this, we recognise that:

```
up_avg1 = (12**1)*up_avg0 + (12**0)*up_walk1
up_avg2 = (12**2)*up_avg0 + (12**1)*up_walk1 + (12**0)*up_walk2 
up_avg3 = (12**3)*up_avg0 + (12**2)*up_walk1 + (12**1)*up_walk2  + (12**0)*up_walk3
```

...and so on. This allows us to express all your unknown values of `up_avg` (your `nan` values) as the product of some calculation relying on three things, all of which you know at the outset:

1. Your constant (`12`)
2. Your first known value of `up_avg` (`up_avg0 = 0.36642`)
3. all your known values of `up_walk` (`up_walk1`, `up_walk2`, `up_walk3`, etc).

Like this:

```
[up_avg1]             [12  ]     [1    0    0]   [up_walk1]
[up_avg2] = up_avg0 * [144 ]  +  [12   1    0] * [up_walk2]  
[up_avg3]             [1728]     [144  12   1]   [up_walk3]
```

Therefore, instead of looping and calculating each nan value one by one, you can express this math as (basically) a single step matrix algebra problem and solve it that way - kinda like this.

*Fair warning - I'm not an expert in numpy or pandas - so the implementation here might be clumsy - the rationalisation of the math is what I'm trying to get across.*

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
   
num_rows_in_dataframe = df['index'].size
# sets num_rows_in_dataframe to 4
constant = 12
# this is the value you want to multiply by each "previous" up_avg value
up_avg_1 = df['up_avg'][0]
# this is the first up_avg value you have = 0.36642

toeplitz_c = np.arange(num_rows_in_dataframe-1)
toeplitz_r = np.hstack((np.array([1]), np.zeros((num_rows_in_dataframe-2))))
powers = toeplitz(toeplitz_c, toeplitz_r)
# these three rows basically constuct this matrix:
    # [0., 0., 0.]
    # [1., 0., 0.]
    # [2., 1., 0.]
    
# We then raise your constant to the powers in this matrix:
constant_array = constant**powers
# which gives us:
    # [  1.,   1.,   1.]
    # [ 12.,   1.,   1.]
    # [144.,  12.,   1.]

# We then take the bottom triangle of this matrix:
constant_array = np.tril(constant_array)

# Giving us this matrix:
    # [  1.,   0.,   0.]
    # [ 12.,   1.,   0.]
    # [144.,  12.,   1.]
# We pick up all the "same row" values of up_walk and place them in a vector:
up_walk = np.array(df['up_walk'])[1:][:, np.newaxis]
    # [1.550781]
    # [0.957031]
    # [0.      ]

# And finally, putting it all together:
replace_nans_with = np.matmul(constant_array, up_walk) + (up_avg_1*constant**np.arange(1, num_rows_in_dataframe))[:, np.newaxis]

# We get an array of your missing nans:
    # [  5.947821]
    # [ 72.330883]
    # [867.970596]
```

Finally put this vector of values in place of your `nan` values and you're home.

This isn't really the "efficient loop" you were after, but (unless I'm missing something) it is a "non-loopy" way to solve the problem and should help you do the job faster - I'd be keen to know if running it this way does in fact prove faster - please try it and let me know.

Comment: wow, amazing approach to this problem. I tried and yes this runs faster than a loop. the only problem is that you need to use a small constant for calculating large dataframes.

Comment: True, the constant powers will become very large very fast. You could only get around it by breaking your dataset into big chunks. Anyway thanks for trying it!